# Why am I getting different outputs from parted and fdisk?

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk, parted

note: I am a Linux beginner, and trying to learn from the following [book: How Linux Works](https://books.google.de/books/about/How_Linux_Works.html?id=wOGUuoHUyAEC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Running `parted -l` I get:

```
Model: KBG30ZMV256G TOSHIBA (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   256GB  256GB  ext4
```

While running `fdisk-l` I get:

```
...

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238,5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BCB099F2-0FCD-4A90-83C2-A76C3E49682D

Device           Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 500117503 499066880  238G Linux filesystem
```

---

Another thing I noticed when running `lsblk -a`:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   238G  0 part /
```

I have a basic understanding of the difference between creating partitions with fdisk vs. parted; however, I am curious about: Why do I get a different output (and partition sizes) between fdisk and parted?

my system information running `uname -a`:

```
Linux  5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outputs from `parted` and `fdisk` are somewhat different but not contradictory.

- `parted` shows values expressed in units you see in its output (`kB`, `MB`, `GB`).
- `fdisk` shows values expressed in physical sectors which in your case are of the size `512 bytes`.

The latter values are *strict*. Their granularity is one sector. You do not need better granularity (e.g. in bytes) because partitions cannot start in the middle of a sector or contain fractional number of sectors. You can recalculate the values to bytes is you want.

Values expressed in units like kB or MB not only are rounded, but there is an ambiguity: see [**Is it true that 1 MB can mean either 1000000 bytes, 1024000 bytes, or 1048576 bytes?**](https://superuser.com/q/373579/432690) Because of this ambiguity the size of `256GB` (from `parted`) and `238G` (from `fdisk`) are both "right", only they use different units.

Take the strict size of `/dev/nvme0n1p2`, it's 499066880 sectors. Multiply by the sector size (512 bytes). The result is 255522242560. Divide by 10<sup>9</sup> and round the result. You get 256.

Now take 255522242560, divide by 1024<sup>3</sup> and round the result. You get 238.